# How do I make my banner image stretch to fit the width of the page if the page width exceeds image width?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

Best visible here: http://blurrapp.com

(It's the big green banner image.)

Right now I capped the image at 2560px in width, and until the 4k revolution comes along that should be fine. But if someone does happen to stretch it even wider for some reason (over multiple monitors?) I want it to not repeat as it currently does, but stretch the image's width to fit.

Is this possible to do through CSS and not needing JavaScript?

That part of my SASS just looks like this:

```
.banner {
    @include box-shadow(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30) 0 4px 10px 0);
    background: url(../images/banner-bg.jpg);
    height: 522px;
```

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add:

```
background-size: cover;
```

This ensures that the image will cover the entire area, in your case the image will almost always retain its height until the width of the banner becomes greater than the original width of the image, then it will start to expand in size to fit the width. It won't look perfect if someone expands their browser to this size but not much will at this width anyway.

http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/